# How can I access to my 4G router externally?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I need to access to my 4G router externally, but when I set up port forwarding on my router, and I try to access it, its public IP doesn't work.

I have a TP-Link router, and the router GUI, gives me `100.x.x.x` public IP, and the "What is my IP" services, gives me another public IP, but neither of them work.

I read something about ISP CGNAT: Can you explain me better what they are?

There is a way to access to my router externally?

Comment: Why? What’s your specific use case? Depending on the actual goal (which most certainly doesn’t end at setting up port forwarding), various alternatives are feasible.